# Slot machine TimeLine animation not working

Tags: java, animation, javafx, timeline

I am trying to develop a slot machine reel application. I have a custom reel pane which adds children vertically. When a spin button is clicked children have to move and when the last child reaches a boundary it has to shift its position above the first child. What I did is shown below.

```
public class ReelPane extends Pane {

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();


    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {

        List<Node> managed = getChildren();
        double y = 0;
        for (Node node : managed) {
            node.setLayoutX(0);
            node.setLayoutY(y);
            y += node.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
        }
    }

    public void spin() {
        List<Node> managed = getChildren();
        double dy = 4;
        for (Node node : managed) {
            timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(2000),new KeyValue(node.layoutYProperty(),node.getLayoutY()+dy)));

            if(node.getLayoutY()>=600){
                node.setLayoutY(-50);
            }

        }
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

fxml file

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import sample.ReelPane?>
<Pane stylesheets="@css/slot.css"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <ReelPane fx:id="reel" styleClass="container">

        <ImageView fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100">
            <Image url="/sample/resources/apple.png"/>
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100">
            <Image url="/sample/resources/diamond.png"/>
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100">
            <Image url="/sample/resources/glass.png"/>
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100">
            <Image url="/sample/resources/grape.png"/>
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100">
            <Image url="/sample/resources/star.png"/>
        </ImageView>
    </ReelPane>

    <Button fx:id="spin" text="SPIN"/>
</Pane>
```

controller

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    ReelPane reel;
    @FXML
    Button spin;

    public void initialize() {
        spin.setOnAction(event -> reel.spin());
    }
}
```

main

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application  {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
         Parent root = 
       FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("resources/fxml/slot.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 900));
        primaryStage.show();

}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But the children are not moving when button is clicked.Can someone tell what went wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. That will make it easier for me to try and reproduce the behavior you claim to be getting when you run your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much simpler tool for the needed animation is `PauseTransition`. 
If you do not want to specify the layout in the fxml you can override layoutChildren() as you did **but** you'll need to disable automatic layout (layoutChildren()) so the animation can change positions:

```
import java.util.List;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ReelPane extends Pane {

    private List<Node> managed;
    private double dy, numberOfCchildren;
    private boolean isAnimating = false;
    private static final double PAUSE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {

        if(isAnimating) return;
        managed = getChildren();
        numberOfCchildren = managed.size();
        double y = 0;
        for (Node node : managed) {
            node.setLayoutX(0);
            node.setLayoutY(y);
            dy = Math.max(dy, node.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()); //dy stores the highest
            y += dy;
        }
    }
    public void spin() {

        isAnimating = true;
        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(PAUSE));
        pause.setOnFinished(event ->{
            for (Node node : managed) {

                if(node.getLayoutY()>= (numberOfCchildren -1) * dy){
                    node.setLayoutY(-dy);
                }
                node.setLayoutY(node.getLayoutY() +dy);
            }
            pause.play();
        });

        pause.play();
    }
}
```

Consider disabling the button while spinning:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    ReelPane reel;
    @FXML
    Button spin;

    public void initialize() {

        spin.setOnAction(event -> {
            reel.spin();
            spin.setDisable(true);
        });
    }
}
```

To make the code [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here is the `slot.fxml` using publicly available resources:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import fx_tests.ReelPane?>

<Pane 
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      fx:controller="fx_tests.sample.Controller">

    <ReelPane fx:id="reel">

        <ImageView fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100">
            <Image url="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Box_Green.png"/>
        </ImageView>

       <ImageView fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100" >
            <Image url="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Box_Red.png"/>
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100">
            <Image url="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Box_Yellow.png"/>
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100" >
           <Image url="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Box_Blue.png"/>
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView fitHeight="100" fitWidth="100">
            <Image url="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/Box_Orange.png"/>
        </ImageView>

    </ReelPane>

    <Button fx:id="spin" text="SPIN" layoutX="20." layoutY="550.0" />

</Pane>
```

A test application:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application  {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root =
        FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("slot.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 600));
        primaryStage.show();

}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I have already assigned the layout value in ReelPane layoutChildren method                         ```    protected void layoutChildren() {

        List<Node> managed = getChildren();
        double y = 0;
        for (Node node : managed) {
            node.setLayoutY(y);
            node.setLayoutX(0);
            y += node.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
        }
    }

Comment: I'm trying to develop a custom reel pane inside which I can add images and buttons without specifying layoutx and layouty values. I have added the code for adding children vertically as in vbox inside the layoutchildren method. After that, I run the same animation code and it is not working

Comment: "_without specifying layoutx and layouty values_" I can't see this requirement in the post. Further more `Reel` is  a `Pane` and not a `VBox` so you need to set the position. The animation can be achieved with `VBox` but it requires a different approach.

Comment: ReelPane is a pane that adds children vertically using layoutchildren() method inside it. So I don't want to specify layoutx and layouty values explicitly.I have added the layoutchildren code inside reelpane.java

Comment: The previous solution I posted was wrong, and did not work correctly. See the new correct and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

All of the `KeyFrame`s of your `Timeline` are scheduled at the same time. Furthermore the `if` statement is executed before you even start the animation.

Imho it's easier to put all the elements in a `VBox` and simply repeatedly change `translateY` repeatedly from a negative value equal to the element height to 0 and move the last element to the front at the end of the cycle. You may want to apply a `clip` to the parent of the `VBox` though to hide anything exceeding the bounds of a single element.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    VBox pane = new VBox();
    Pane parent = new Pane(pane);
    parent.setPrefSize(50, 50);
    parent.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    parent.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(pane.translateYProperty(), -50d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), evt -> {
                pane.getChildren().get(pane.getChildren().size() - 1).toBack();
            }, new KeyValue(pane.translateYProperty(), 0d)));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50, Color.RED.interpolate(Color.BLACK, i / 6d));
        pane.getChildren().add(rect);
    }
    parent.setClip(new Rectangle(50, 50));
    timeline.play();
    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(parent), 200, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```